# tcpdump in Kali Linux VM does not capture scp between two devices

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kali-linux, scp, tcpdump

**Situation**:
I'm learning how to develop tests for a hardened server my company is developing for a client. The test configuration will consist of the test target (the server we're developing) and an external test laptop, which I'll use to run some test scripts.

The test laptop and the server will both be running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. However, I'm posting here because this setup also involves Kali Linux. Apologies if this isn't the correct site to post to.

Using Kali Linux in a VirtualBox VM on the test laptop, I need to analyze packets transferred between the test laptop and the target server. I've been using *Learning Kali Linux* (an O'Reilly textbook) and this [resource](http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c6055/labs/lab1-ans.pdf) to build a simple environment in which I can accomplish this, but have reached a dead end.

**Process**:

When I configure the network of the Kali Linux VM to be NAT, I can successfully `ping` the IP addresses of the target server and the host laptop from the Kali Linux VM.

I can also successfully `ping` the host laptop from the target server, and vice-versa.

But, when I execute the `tcpdump port 22` command in the VM, then perform an `scp` from the target server to the host laptop, I see no packet data in the Kali Linux shell.

Similarly, if I run `tcpdump -i any` in Kali Linux, I do get a stream, but it's a very slow trickle of `eth0` data (the wired connection between the host and target server). Conversely, when I execute the same command on the host laptop outside of the VM I get a healthy flow of info.

Then, when I configure the network of the Kali Linux VM to be a Host-Only Adapter, all of the devices can `ping` each other (makes sense to me because they share a network now).

When I execute `tcpdump port 22` and attempt to `scp` from server to host, I get packet data this time. Great! Except, the `scp` fails to complete. I don't get an error message in the Bash window of the server where I executed `scp` though—it appears to get 'hung-up' and never completes. I have to kill the process.

Even after I shut down the Kali Linux VM this remains true: `scp` fails to complete. Interestingly, when I run `ifconfig` on the test laptop I can see that the Host-Only Adapter VirtualBox created still persists. If I reboot the host, the network disappears, and I can once again successfully `scp` from the target server to the host. I now suspect this is a networking issue that I fail to grasp.

Can anyone offer some help with this problem?

PS, I can execute `tcpdump` on the host laptop (outside the VM) and see the data stream. Worse comes to worse I'll use that method. This is really a question of curiosity on the topic of networking between devices and how to monitor that networking using Kali Linux. I didn't choose to open Pandora's Box, yet here I am.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, network adapter hardware discards frames not intended for the local host.  In order to be able to capture all network traffic, a sniffer like `tcpdump` needs to be able to put the network interface into *promiscuous mode*, where all frames are delivered to the network stack.  On a VM, putting the virtual adapter into promiscuous mode doesn't necessarily affect the host (physical hardware) environment, so it is ineffective.  That's why it works outside the VM.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. So, I reviewed the configuration of my VM network and confirmed that the interface was set to promiscuous mode as you recommended. I think that, because my network was configured properly, I was able to see that 'something' was happening between the host and the client. However, the issue of ```scp``` not working while the Host-Only Adapter network is live persists. Rather than solve the issue, I'm instead using the host directly, rather than the Kali Linux VM.